# How to Draw Stacked Bar Graphs in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, graph, core-plot

I want to draw Stack Bar Graph in iOS application in the given link

http://peltiertech.com/images/2009-05/StackChart4.png

.I Know to draw Simple Bar Graphs using core plot,but could not find a way to draw Stacked Bar Graphs.Please Can anyone suggest me the way to draw Stacked Bar Graphs using core plot or any other libraries.Please suggest any other libraries available to draw this in iOS application.

Comment: Hi any updates on this post , did u figure out the way to do this in objective c

Answer (score 5):

Core Plot won't do the stacking calculations for you, but it can draw the bars. You'll need one bar plot for each data series. For example, you could draw one bar from 0 to 2 with one plot. The next plot could have a bar that spans between 2 and 5 and a third plot could go between 5 and 6.

The way to set this up is to set `barBasesVary` = YES for all but the bottom plot in the stack. These plots will ask the datasource for an additional plot field called `CPTBarPlotFieldBarBase`. Use that to set the starting value for the bar and use `CPTBarPlotFieldBarTip` to set the end point as usual.

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't be too hard to do this in Core Graphics.  I don't believe Core Plot provides this (or any other library I have tried) - but this graph looks pretty simplistic.  There was a great session at WWDC 2011 on using Core Graphics, and you can view it here (Dev account required):

https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/includes/practical-drawing-for-ios-developers.html#practical-drawing-for-ios-developers

Comment: Apple removed this session and move to this link: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/129/